# To excess insulin releasing / to excess releases of insulin?

Tags: infinitives

I don't know which variant (the bold text) I should use.

> Sweeteners can reduce the intake of simple sugars to a level which does not provoke the pancreas **to excess insulin releasing / to excess releases of insulin**.

Answer (score 7):

Neither of those.  I would say:

> Sweeteners can reduce the intake of simple sugars to a level which
>   does not provoke the pancreas **to release excess insulin.**